# How to use Java LZO Library?

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle-eclipse

I am trying to use LZO Compression Decompression Library in my Java Program but I could not find a single example how to use it for compression and decompression of data.How to write main function so that it would work as entry point for my code.
I visited from ([Java LZO compression library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804588/java-lzo-compression-library)), but I did not gotten any reference.

I am implementing github code from [Here:](https://github.com/Karmasphere/lzo-java)

When I compile this above github code in Eclipse then Error occurred.

example:`selection does not contain main type`